# Delete Button in Jquery table from SQL Server in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server

I am new in asp.net MVC and javascript. I tried to delete  record from SQL Database in jquery table for a particular row. I am adding different methods but it is failing. Please solve my  problem. Thanks for Advance..

**This is my View Page**

```
<script>

    $("#txtcategory").change(function () {
        var tcity = $("#txt_city").val();
        var ta_add = $("#txta_address").val();
        var tb_add = $("#txtb_address").val();
        var t_dt = $("#txtdate").val();
        var cat = $("#txtcategory").val();

        $.get("get_data", { city: tcity, dt: t_dt, a_add: ta_add, b_add: tb_add, cate: cat }, function (data) {
            var row;
            $("#tbl_data").empty();
            row = "<tr><th>Category</th><th>Vehicle Number</th><th>Date</th></tr>";
            $.each(data, function (i, v1) {

                row += "<tr><td>" + v1.CATEGORY + "</td><td>" + v1.VEHICLE_NUMBER + "</td><td>" + v1.S_DATE + "</td> "+ 
                //"< td > " + " < input type= 'button' id= '" + v1.ID + "' value= 'Delete' > " + "</td > "+
                    "<td>" + "<button type='button' id='"+v1.ID+"' class='deleteContact btn btn btn- danger btn- xs'>Delete</button>"+"</td>"+
                    "</tr>"
            });
            $("#tbl_data").append(row);

        })

    });

    $(document).on("click", ".deleteContact", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // closest used to remove the respective 'tr' in which I have my controls   
    }); 
</script>
```

**This is my Model Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace fiverr_Map_Project.Models
{
    public class Crud_Class
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string CITY { get; set; }
        public string A_LATLNG { get; set; }
        public string A_ADDRESS { get; set; }
        public string B_LATLNG { get; set; }
        public string B_ADDRESS { get; set; }
        public string CATEGORY { get; set; }
        public string VEHICLE_NUMBER { get; set; }
        public DateTime T_DATE { get; set; }
        public string S_DATE { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**This is My DB Class**

```
public DataSet show_data(string city,DateTime dt,string a_add,string b_add,string cate)
        {

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select category,vehicle_number,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t_date, 101) as t_date from vehicle_entry where " +
" city = '"+city+"' and t_date = '"+dt+"' and a_address = '"+a_add+"'" +
" and b_address = '"+b_add+"' and category = '"+cate+"'", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
```

**Home Controller**

```
 public JsonResult get_data(string city, DateTime dt, string a_add, string b_add, string cate)
        {
            DataSet ds = dblayer.show_data(city,dt,a_add,b_add,cate);
            List<Crud_Class> listreg = new List<Crud_Class>();
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                listreg.Add(new Crud_Class
                {


                    CATEGORY = dr["category"].ToString(),
                    VEHICLE_NUMBER = dr["vehicle_number"].ToString(),
                    S_DATE =dr["t_date"].ToString()
                });
            }
            return Json(listreg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Please help me. My Project have very short time. Thanks

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This is a textbook example of sql injection. My friend bobby tables loves code like this. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Well you don't have a delete statement anywhere. You need that to delete the data from the database. Perhaps sharing what you mean by "it is failing" would help. Do you get an error? Does it do (or maybe not do) something you think it should? Unfortunately this question has no direction or explanation of what you need help with.